# put element on the right of another on top of progressbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making one progressbar with jquery mobile. There is one indication on the top of the progressbar that indicate something and the position of that element is defined :

[image: bar with initial text]

Here is the code :

```
<div class="ui-slider ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all" style="border:none; margin:8px 0 0 0;">
<div class="ui-slider-bg ui-btn-active ui-btn-corner-all progressBarBackground " style="width: 0.56%; height:100%; padding:0; border:none">
</div>
<span style="left: 50%;display:block; position:absolute;top:-20px;font-size:12px;">
↓ Initial text (arrow don't move)
</span>
</div>
```

How can I add a text **BEFORE** the indication text without changing the position of the initial text?

If I add "`Append text` " before the "`↓ Initial text (arrow don't move)`", the arrow will moved of the space taken by the "`Append text` "!

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try using `span:before { content:"Append text"; }`

Just make sure that the span you want to append the text to has an id or class for CSS referencing.